# C++ Simple Thread Pool

Tags: c++, threadpool

I am trying to implement a simple thread pool in c++ as follows:

```
class worker {
public:
    worker();
    thread mThread;
private:
    void run();
};

worker::worker() {
    (this->mThread = thread(&worker::run, this)).detach();
}

class threadpool {
public:
    threadpool(int size);
    void addTask();
private:
    vector<worker> workers;
};
```

But when I add the constructor of threadpool:

```
threadpool::threadpool(int size) {
    this->workers = vector<worker>(size, worker());
}
```

I get an "attempting to reference a deleted function" error which as far as I know it means that somewhere in my code I am trying to copy a thread. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Close, you were trying to assign to a thread. You also seem to avoid using  initializer lists, which is why you see this  error.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smallest possible change is to:

```
threadpool::threadpool(int size) {
    this->workers = vector<worker>(size);
}
```

That said, initialiser lists are sweet.

```
threadpool::threadpool(int size)
  : workers{size}
{ }
```

(You *should* change from `int size` to `size_t` or - if you're feeling saintly - `vector<worker>::size_type`).

It was the provision of a prototypical `worker()` object that requested copying, the implicit constructor for which was deleted because you'd provided an explicit default constructor.

Comment: @dchatzis: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00a8235a0068803f) it is working - are you using a C++11 compliant compiler?  Keep in mind the threads are detached so may not run before your program terminates - you probably want a `cin.get()` or something to block the main thread's exit.

Comment: I use vs2013. With the initializer list everything is ok but your first solution gives error

Comment: @dchatzis: my guess the VS2013 compiler hasn't updated the vector constuctor: in C++03 it was required to default construct a prototypical object and would have had the same issue, in C++11 it shouldn't.  Anyway, all good moving to the initialiser list.

Comment: What if worker constructor had an argument like: `worker(threadpool pool)` ?

Comment: @dchatzis: then I'd say the design was very poor - what would worker want with a *by-value* `threadpool`?  Keeping a reference back to the spawning `threadpool` I can imagine.  Are you throwing out random questions, or do you have a specific function you're trying to add to the design?  If so, explain what you're trying to achieve and we can discuss how best to do it....